# Font embedding reliable?

Tags: embedded-fonts

How reliable is font embedding for a very large production site and if relevant, would you do anything special to test cross browser, device, etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with font-embedding as long as you ensure that it works across all browsers and under heavy load.

Always do testing on IE6+ (IE6-IE9), FireFox 3.5+, Opera, Konqueror, Google Chrome, etc. Also make sure you can view everything from a mobile such as the iPhone, HTC Desire, etc.

If you have any doubts that it won't work, then don't use it, or use it under GREAT precautions.

Just do your testing and ensure that nothing is wrong with it before you put it live.